# Parsing emails for images in signature section

Tags: java, image, parsing, email, attachment

have a program which checks the unread email from an inbox, parses and sends the content of the email to a record. If there are any images in the email, those images will be sent as attachments to the record. Now if any email is having an image in the signature part of the email, that image is also being sent as an attachment.

Is there a way that I can check for the images in the signature part of the email and ignore them? or Is there a way around where I can skip the entire signature content from getting parsed?

If it is difficult to parse the signature section of emails coming from different email servers, I would like to know if it is possible for emails coming from outlook?.

Comment: What's the program you are using? Did you make it?
Can you provide an example of a signature you want to remove?

Answer (score 4):

The signature is incorporated in the message when the message is composed.
After the message is sent, there is no way, in general, to tell apart a signature from something that the sender has typed by hand.

But maybe, if the signatures you refer to always have some common format, you can probably detect that particular format, using a regular expression or something like that.

Comment: By RFC, everything after (newline) (dash) (dash) (space) (newline) is the `.signature`. But I don't think Microsoft Outlook believes in RFCs. If you have multiple messages from the same author, you can trim any identical content at the end of the message. Perhaps you could simply block images you have already received, though (and manually remove when a new one slips through).

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't know the two dashes were a part of the standard.
But I often saw the dashes without the trailing space, and of course I saw signatures without them at all (mine for example).